# Migrate an existing project to Firebase : Authentication handling & Preserve existing JWT

Tags: php, angular, firebase, google-app-engine, jwt

I've an existing project that is built on :

- AngularJS
- Google App Engine backend, PHP, with an authentication based on JWT

I'm in process of rewriting the frontend to move to Angular 8 and I want to leverage the firebase features.

I'm currently working on integrating the authentication feature (username/password, google, twitter, facebook etc...)

And I'm thinking about my next step :

- Once my use is authenticated with firebase, how can my GAE PHP backend check that the user is authenticated ?
- In my JWT, I've set some basic user information, that are essential to my backend function.

  - uid, first name, last name, entityId, entityName, roleId, environmentId

I was imagining something like :

- once authenticated with firebase, call my GAE Backend with the OAuth2 token
- call some magic function that will validate the OAuth2 token and associate the firebase user, with my internal user table
- reply with a JWT
- Include the JWT and the OAuth2 token in every call

Would this work ? any suggestions ?

Comment: it seems this article may explain the solution : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine

Comment: with this PHP lib to verify the firebase token : 
https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication.html#verify-a-firebase-id-token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I did it :

On the client side (Angular Application), I use ngx-auth-firebaseui, to display the login form.

On the form, I set the call back that handle an authentication success:

login.component.html

```html
<ngx-auth-firebaseui (onSuccess)="successfulLogin($event)"
                     (onError)="printError($event)">
</ngx-auth-firebaseui>
```

The code of the callback is here.
From the Firebase User object, I call the method getIdTokenResult() to get the firebase JWT.
And I then call my php backend via the authenticationService

login.component.ts

```
successfulLogin(user:User) {

    console.log(user);
    user.getIdTokenResult().then((idTokenResult:IdTokenResult)=> {
      console.log(idTokenResult.token);

      let token : string = idTokenResult.token;
      let rcqJWTToken = this.authenticationService.authenticate( { token } as FirebaseJWT);


      rcqJWTToken.subscribe((rcqToken:string)=> console.log("RCQ JWT Token : '"+rcqToken+"'"));

      this.router.navigate['/welcome'];
    });    
}
```

Here I transmit the Firebase JWT to my php backend
authentication.service.ts

```
  authenticate(firebaseJWTToken:FirebaseJWT):Observable<String>{

    return this.http.post<String>(this.authenticationURL, firebaseJWTToken, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      tap(_ => console.log('fetched RCQ JWT')),
      catchError(this.handleError<String>('authenticate', ""))
    );
  }
```

On the server side :

I set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as an env var, like it is when deployed on Google App Engine

`putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/myuser/.cred/GCP-project-ID.json");`

I use Slimframework, so I instanciate the Firebase object in my dependencies.php file.
With the env var, Firebase do not need anything else.
check here : https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/4.32.0/setup.html

```php
use Kreait\Firebase;
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;

/**
 * Used to authenticate a firebase user, from it's Firebase JWT
 * @property Firebase $firebase
 * @param    \Slim\Container $c
 * @return   Firebase
 */
$container['firebase'] = function (\Slim\Container $c)
{
  $firebase = (new Factory)->create();
  return $firebase;
};
```

and here comes the route where the authentication is done :

```php
$app->post(getPrefix().'/firebase-authenticate', function($request, $response, $args) use ($app)
{
  $token    = $this->clientInputValidator->validateString("token"   , $request->getParsedBodyParam("token"    ), 1500 , true );
  $username = "";
  Logger::dataForLogging(new LoggingEntity(null,  ["username"=>$username]));

  try
  {
    $verifiedIdToken = $this->firebase->getAuth()->verifyIdToken($token);
  }
  catch (InvalidToken $e)
  {
    $response401 = $response->withStatus(401);
    $response401->getBody()->write(json_encode(["error" =>"Authentication error"]));

    $this->logger->error("Firebase authentication error", array('username' => $username, 'token' => $token));

    return $response401;
  }
  $uid  = $verifiedIdToken->getClaim('sub');
  $user = $this->firebase->getAuth()->getUser($uid);


  $this->logger->debug("Firebase JWT checked successfully", array('uid' => $uid,'user' => $user));
});
```

The main thing is here : 
`$verifiedIdToken = $this->firebase->getAuth()->verifyIdToken($token);`

And the user details are retrieved here:

`$user = $this->firebase->getAuth()->getUser($uid);`

I can get the uid, email, and all the info in the Firebase JWT.

the token itself has a TTL of 1 hour, so I'll probably have to refresh the token and revalidate it against my backend.